# One (integer) to Many (array of integers) relation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is it possible to make a One to Many relation betwen two layers where the id of the "One" layer is an integer but the id of the "Many" is an array of integers in postgis? (integer[])

Doing the normal relation in Project -> Properties -> Relations it is not working...

The integer[] field in QGIS is detected as QString, maybe this is the source of the problem...

I am using QGIS 2.18.13

Comment: why yes, that´s perfectly possible in PostgreSQL. sth. like `...FROM <one> AS a JOIN <many> AS b ON a.id = ANY(b.ids)` would be the general condition here. are you looking for SQL solutions?

Comment: @ThingumaBob No, I'm looking for a solution in QGIS itself, without having to create a view in PostgreSQL

Comment: PostgreSQL/PostGIS arrays are not directly supported as field type, thus the *QString*. it's either pyQGIS or SQL I guess...

Comment: are both layers in the DB? btw., no need for a view if you want the joined layer in the project/as file

Comment: @ThingumaBob yes, they are both in the DB